# Insert BLOB using java for both DB2 and Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, db2, blob

I am currently validating an application developed on Oracle for DB2. Since we don't want to maintain two separate sources, I need some query to insert blob into a field, that works in both oracle and db2. I don't have any identifier to distinguish under which DB the application is running.

I used `utl_raw.cast_to_raw`  in oracle and `CAST() as BLOB` in DB2 which are mutually incompatible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to find a common SQL that uses some kind of casting. But you can do this with "plain" SQL using JDBC's `setBinaryStream()`

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
   "insert into blob_table (id, blob_data) values (?, ?)";

File blobFile = new File("your_document.pdf");
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(blobFile);

pstmt.setInt(1, 42);
pstmt.setBinaryStream(2, in, (int)blobFile.length());
pstmt.executeUpdate();
connection.commit();
```

You can use `setBinaryStream()` the same way with an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I have the data inside a variable of type String. Is it fine to use the above method by converting the String to BinaryStream??

Comment: @Saju: how can you have a *binary* large object as a String? What is the actual (e.g. Oracle) datatype for that column? If that is a `CLOB` (rather than a `BLOB`) you should use `setCharacterStream()` instead of `setBinaryStream()`

Comment: Perhaps @Saju means NCLOB in Oracle, DBCLOB in DB2.