# How to create BLOB object?

Tags: java, jdbc, blob

1. How to create BLOB object in Java?
2. How to set the BLOB value from DB?
3. How to set the BLOB value in DB?

I have create the BLOB object like this:

```
byte [] fileId = b.toByteArray();
Blob blob = new SerialBlob(fileId);
```

But it gives me an error.

Comment: Why do you need to create a BLOB object ? Or do you want to read the BLOB data from the DB ?

Comment: I am fetching a BLOB value from db and I want to save this value in BLOB object that's why I want to create a object.After save again I want to save this value in another db that time I want to get that value.I am using spring framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert BLOB using java for both DB2 and Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462060/insert-blob-using-java-for-both-db2-and-oracle)

Answer (score 24):

1. to create BLOB use `Connection.createBlob`
2. to write BLOB to DB use `PreparedStatement.setBlob`
3. to read BLOB from DB use `ResultSet.getBlob`

Assuming you have table `t1` with BLOB column `b1`:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
Blob b1 = conn.createBlob();
b1.setBytes(1, new byte[10]); // first position is 1. Otherwise you get: Value of offset/position/start should be in the range [1, len] where len is length of Large Object[LOB]

PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("update t1 set c1 = ?");
ps.setBlob(1, b1);
ps.executeUpdate();

Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select c1 from t1");
Blob b2 = rs.getBlob(1);
```