# Can't load objects from a ResultSet in Java

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a problem with loading objects from a SQLite database.

First of all, this is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  data BLOB
);
```

This is the simple class which I want to store and reload:

```
public class MyHashMap extends HashMap<String, Integer> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
}
```

Then I'm filling the map with some data and store it with an SQL INSERT statement in the database. Everything works fine and if I execute a SELECT (with the sqlite3 command-line client) I will see the correct information.

Now I'm using the java.sql package to load the object:

```
String sql = "SELECT data FROM MyTable WHERE rowid = 1";
MyHashMap map = null;

try {
  try (Statement stmt = db.createStatement()) {
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
      if (rs.next()) {
        map = rs.getObject("data", MyHashMap.class);
      }
    }
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

There's no exception thrown but my map variable is null. I debugged the program and I can say that the getObject method is called as expected.

Comment: Turn the debug mode and Show query as true and see the query that has been executed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312133/how-to-create-blob-object-in-java?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I read the linked thread but it doesn't helped me becaue I see no possibility to "convert" the Blob interface to my HashMap object.

Comment: maybe the query gets null values.Did you try print the result of query ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you definition of `MyHashMap` is incorrect

```
public class MyHashMap extends HashMap<Integer, String> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
}
```

The main issue, though, is that SQL doesn't store Java objects; it merely stores rows of records, which consist of fields. You need to read these records one by one, and store them in your map. Roughly as follows:

```
MyHashMap map = new MyHashMap();
final String sql = "SELECT rowid, data FROM MyTable";
try (final Statement stmt = connection.createStatement;
        final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        map.put(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2));
    }
 }
```

Please note that there's a good chance that reading a `Blob` into a `String` will fail. Usually, JDBC drivers are clever enough to convert data types, but if you have raw binary data in your blob, you cannot read it into a string. You would need the `getBlob` method instead, and deal with the resulting object. But I can't tell from your code what you'll be storing in that blob.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me: My definition of the HashMap is absolutely correct. The key is a string, the value is a counter.
And then: No, I don't want to read the rowid and a string in the HashMap. My idea was to store the whole HashMap in a BLOB and reload it from there. I read in the documentation that this is possible with serializable classes. rowid is then only an autoincrement for my records.

Comment: Then, the question presents itself why you would want to store a Java object in a database. It's not what a relational database is intended for. But since you already solved your own problem, add it as an answer to this question, and mark it as the accepted answer. it will help other people.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution with the following method:

```
private Object getObjectFromBlob(ResultSet rs, String columnName)
    throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {
  InputStream binaryInput = rs.getBinaryStream(columnName);
  if (binaryInput == null || binaryInput.available() == 0) {
    return null;
  }

  ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(binaryInput);
  try {
    return in.readObject();
  } finally {
    in.close();
  }
}
```