# How do I create a BLOB object by Java without connection to database

Tags: java, blob

Like the title,
I need to create a BLOB object for my unit test.

**I read this**

> [How to create BLOB object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312133/how-to-create-blob-object-in-java)

But it needs to connect to a specific database.

Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Since `BLOB` is an `interface`, you could create your own mock/proxy which will facilitate your requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this way is ok:

```
byte[] bytes = "A byte array".getBytes();
Blob blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(bytes);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since BLOB is an expensive resource and you are doing a test, mocking is a great way to create a BLOB.

Also with this, you can control what the BLOB is without actually reading through a large object.

How to do it depends entirely on the testing framework you are using. Example, this is how it is done in Mockito: `Blob blob = mock(Blob.class);`