# How to pass long json with more than 60000 characters

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, blob, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a stored procedure which does insertion into a table. How can I insert json data which can be up to 64KB? The column `request_params` is of type blob.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE INSERT_USER
(in_user_id IN VARCHAR2,
in_user_name IN VARCHAR2,
in_request_params IN VARCHAR2) 
AS 
BEGIN
    insert into user_table(user_id,user_name,request_params) 
    values(in_user_id,in_user_name,in_request_params);

END INSERT_USER;
```

Comment: If the column is BLOB, why is `in_request_parms` a string? Even if you made it a CLOB instead of VARCHAR2 to allow the size you need, you'd need to then convert that to a BLOB. Is the caller actually passing a string, or does/can it pass a BLOB directly?

Comment: how to pass blob from JAVA  applictain ? I mean can I covert JSON string to blob in JAVA

Comment: I think I got the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609535/how-to-convert-json-object-to-blob-in-java

Answer (score 0):

> The column `request_params` is of type blob.

Then use a `BLOB`:

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE INSERT_USER(
  in_user_id        IN VARCHAR2,
  in_user_name      IN VARCHAR2,
  in_request_params IN BLOB
)
AS 
BEGIN
  insert into user_table(user_id,user_name,request_params) 
  values(in_user_id,in_user_name,in_request_params);
END INSERT_USER;
/
```

or the same types as the table's columns (which would also be a `BLOB`):

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE INSERT_USER(
  in_user_id        IN user_table.user_id%TYPE,
  in_user_name      IN user_table.user_name%TYPE,
  in_request_params IN user_table.request_params%TYPE
)
AS 
BEGIN
  insert into user_table(user_id,user_name,request_params) 
  values(in_user_id,in_user_name,in_request_params);
END INSERT_USER;
/
```

> how to pass blob from JAVA applictain ? I mean can I covert JSON string to blob in JAVA

Use the `PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream` or `PreparedStatement.setBlob` functions. An example is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462060/insert-blob-using-java-for-both-db2-and-oracle/16462192#16462192) (and if you have a JSON string then just get the bytes from the string and stream that to the blob).

Comment: request_params  from java is JSON string

Comment: @Ankita A JSON string is just a string and a string is just a series of bytes.

Comment: I tried something 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609535/how-to-convert-json-object-to-blob-in-java

But java is giving error

Comment: @Ankita "I tried something ... But java is giving an error" is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us exactly what code you used in your attempt or what the error was so there is nothing that we can debug. If you are having issues with this then you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a complete [MRE]. (Rather than trying to debug it in comments).

Comment: However, I would suggest that you use `new ByteArrayInputStream(yourJSONString.getBytes());` and pass it to `PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream` rather than trying to create a `BLOB` object.